# How to avoid move elision when passing a temporary by value?

Tags: c++, move-semantics, copy-elision

In the following code:

```
Widget makeWidget()
{
    return Widget();
}

void foo(Widget widget)
{
   ...
}

foo(makeWidget());
```

the Widget object will be always constructed in-place (inside foo function), so no move construction takes place (at least with all compilers I've tried). What are simple examples of passing a temporary to a function by value in a way that move construction will actually take place (without explicitly moving, i.e. using std::move)?

Comment: I'm curious, why do you want to avoid move ellision?

Comment: I just want to understand C++ better.

Comment: Are you looking for gcc flags `-fno-elide-constructors` ?

Answer (score 3):

The criterion for elision in this case is:

> when a temporary class object that has not been bound to a reference would be copied/moved to a class object with the same cv-unqualified type

So a simple way to prevent elision would be to bind it to a reference:

```
foo(std::move(makeWidget());
```

Comment: I had implicit moves on my mind, so no std::move. I've edited my original question. Sorry for not being specific enough.

Comment: @rubix_addict: In that case, I've no idea what you're asking. If you pass a temporary by value to a function with the same parameter type, then the move can be elided. There are no examples of it not being elided.

Answer (score 0):

[Gcc](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.9.0/gcc/C_002b_002b-Dialect-Options.html) has the flag `-fno-elide-constructors` which disables copy elision. With that option, both of the moves will be done in your example code.